# Yii2 register and auto login

Tags: php, yii2

My problem is: I have a buy now form and I need to register and log in the user before I redirect to the bank's payment page. All the details from is in a bootstrap modal, and I send it with jQuery post (`$.post()`).

My User class in Yii2: `class User extends ActiveRecord implements IdentityInterface`

And here is the register and login:

```
$user = new User();
$user->email = $email;
$user->password = $password;
if($user->save()) {
    \Yii::$app->user->login($user, 3600 * 24 * 30)
}
```

The user created, but if I relad the page, it's still not logged in. The `\Yii::$app->user->login()` returns with true.

I tried to put this before the login:

```
$session = \Yii::$app->session;
if (!$session->isActive) {
    $session->open();
}
```

But not helped. I'm sure the problem is the ajax login but how can I do it right?

EDIT:

I have created a test:

```
public function actionLoginTest()
{
    $session = \Yii::$app->session;
    $session->open();

    $user = User::findOne(163);
    echo '<pre>';
    echo 'logged before login: ' . (int) \Yii::$app->user->getId() . PHP_EOL;
    echo 'isGuest before login: ' . (\Yii::$app->user->isGuest ? 'yes' : 'no') . PHP_EOL;
    \Yii::$app->user->login($user, 3600 * 24 * 30);
    echo 'isGuest after login: ' . (\Yii::$app->user->isGuest ? 'yes' : 'no') . PHP_EOL;
    echo 'logged user: ' . \Yii::$app->user->getId();
}
```

This is the response on every reload:

```
logged before login: 0
isGuest before login: yes
isGuest after login: no
logged user: 163
```

So never login...

Comment: Thanks but it just a typo in the question.

Comment: Do you have ‘enableAutoLogin' option in config?

Comment: @stig-js Yes. If I dump the cookies before and after login, they are same. So the cookie is generated, but unused.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't echo things from an action, you need to return them. 
Might even be the reason it's not able to output the identity cookie (you should have 2 cookies: one for the session and one for the identity). I wouldn't be amazed if your log contains errors about not being able to send the headers because content is already sent.

Comment: Of course not the error reporting was the problem. If a method has return value I can echo it without any problem. And yes I had 2 cookies.

Comment: So if you know everything better, why ask the question? What you return from your action is added to the response and it is that response, at the end of the request, that takes care of outputting the new headers (which set the cookies). If you `echo` from the action, you have already sent output, which prevents new cookies from being sent... Think about it for a second...

Comment: I advice you to check yii\web\CookieCollection. There is no problem with echo until I get 'headers already sent' warning. BTW the problem solved and It wasn't related to creating cookies.

Answer (score 1):

I found the source of the problem. The problem was the identity cookie usage. In my `User` model the `findIdentity($id)` method had an extra filter to enable login for only active users.